# CKEditor: *During* WYSIWYG edit, how to show caption beneath image?

Tags: 7, entities, media, wysiwyg

When editing a body field with image and caption, the caption does not *display* during editing. Once saved it is visible - when the content is viewed.

Implementation-wise, I've added a caption field to the Image entity via the Entity View Mode config pages - admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/fields

Any thoughts on how to get the caption to show during edit?

CKEditor 4.3 supports captions but there would need to be support for the Drupal side of the implementation.

Comment: Hey, I have two questions: 1) Do you need the caption when you're just attaching the image to the node or when you're embedding it into the body with the CKEditor image button?  And 2) when you say image caption, you're not talking about the image alt attribute, are you?

Comment: Thanks @Boriana for your interest in this question, my answers to your questions: 1) I don't use the image with the node like this, I use the Wysiwyg button for image to embed the image in the edit area. On clicking the button it asks for image source e.g. upload, library, etc. and then the caption. 2) Correct. I've added a caption field to the image entity by visiting the admin page admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/fields as mentioned.

Comment: Have you seen the video at http://vimeo.com/69750074? This is a demo of work being done for Drupal 8 but maybe you could back-port. See https://drupal.org/node/2027181.

Comment: thanks it's a nice idea but I wasn't expecting to do a backport from Drupal 8 to solve my problem. I'd like to but I have limited time. I think I should explore other options, including my own answer before considering doing a backport

Comment: hi, were u able to find a solution for ckeditor ?

Comment: Not yet. Once edit is complete and the content is saved the caption does appear but it would be nice if it appeared *while* editing. Having looked at few solutions it would appear that most people get stumped with this same issue.

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old thread - but I'm trying to solve the same problem. I've got the caption working using the blog linked above in media manager itself, but the caption field does not even show if uploading direct through the 'embed media' button in the CKEditor. Did you get this element working in your solution?

Comment: Not a problem at all steve. Unfortunately not. We accepted the limitation. 8 months on from when this question was originally asked, I'm guessing that this is still the case with the current codebase given that you have looked at it about a day ago.

Answer (score 1):

As of CKEditor 4.3, they now have widgets in the CKEditor side. They have introduced the Image2 plugin/widget, which supports image captions. The problem I've seen here is that Drupal has not caught up with this, so if you're using the media module for a file browser, it looks like that functionality is not yet ported to this newer version. However, if you just care about captions, it works.

See: http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2 for the plugin. I've been using it with the CKEditor Module, but it should work just as fine with WYSIWYG + Ckeditor Library.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with my colleagues (thanks folks!), their idea for a solution is to write a filter for the JSON generated by the WYSIWYG.

The caption text is present in the JSON. So, extending the existing filter ought to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some more research and I gather you have gone down the Media/File Entity/Entity View Modes route as described at http://www.58bits.com/blog/2013/03/06/how-to-add-captions-to-images-in-drupal.

That seems a heck of a lot of work to go to in order to write a caption under an image and it is still not wysiwyg.

So here is another answer using Wysiwyg/TinyMCE and the dev version of Caption Filter. See discussion at https://drupal.org/node/696734. (Edit. There was some work done on integrating with CKEditor too but I don't think this has been committed although there are some patches, should it be important for you to stick with CKEditor.)

The upshot is as shown below. I was pleased to find I could put html in the caption.
[image: Example of image with caption in wysisyg editor.]

Comment: Thanks a lot but it does have to be CKEditor. I'm getting a little bit closer to a solution that involves media module filtering, either in its js or php.

Answer (score 0):

There are conflicts between the CKeditor Image2 plugin and Media module. If you're looking to align + caption your images while maintaining the media tag in your WYSIWYG, the most current recipe can be found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2843391